# check this list for a puzzle word game

Tags: python

The point is to create a word game, scramble the word and solve it. I need guidance to see if I did the shuffle, guesses (count,if right,if wrong), and if it repeats properly, right:

```
def main():

    print("Welcome to my game, solve the puzzle.")

    print("lets play")


    wordlist= open("wordlist.txt", "r")

    import random

    def randomWord(wordlist):
        wIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordlist)- 1)
        return wordlist[wIndex]
        print("Here is the word: ")


    def displayGame(wrong, right):
        print("Wrong Guesses:", end=" ")
        for letter in wrong:
            print(letter, end=" ")
        print()


        blanks = '-'*len(secret)

    for i in range(0, len(secret) - 1):
        if secret[1] in right:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secret[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end=" ")
        print()

    def getguess(guessed):
        while True:
            guess = input()
            guess = guess.lower()
            if len(guess) != 1:
                print("Enter you letter.")
            elif guess in guessed:
                print("Try again, you have already use that letter.")
            elif guess not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
                print("please enter a letter")
            else:
                return guess

    def playAgain():
        print("Would you like to play again? (yes or no)", end=" ")
        while True:
            keepGoing = input()
            if keepGoing == "yes":
                return True
            elif keepGoing == "no":
                return False
            else:
                print("yes or no please.")
```

main

Comment: what is the issue? You just want to know if your code is right?

Comment: "*I need guidance to see if I did [it] right"* - have you considered **testing** it?!

Comment: consider posting your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This code is not a good fit for us unless it is verified that it works. Just because it is off topic here does not mean it is on topic at CR.

Comment: There is so much wrong it is difficult to know where to start, quite disorientating.

Comment: just to see if its right, yes. I have tested it, it runs, but nothing happens

Comment: @get2thechopper so what you're saying is that it runs, but it doesn't produce the result you're looking for? That's what testing is for -- to find out HOW it's not producing that result. Throw some `print` statements in key places, or learn to use the `logging` module and redirect it to a file, or write some unit tests with the `unittest` module. Or at the VERY least, tell us what it SHOULD be doing, and what is IS doing.

Comment: @get2thechopper I'll tell you right off the bat that nothing is ever running because you only ***define*** `main`, you never run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of things going wrong here, and I've taken the time to go through your code and note where specific lines are wrong. You can find that list [here](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/d3707ae1246198592b43) but it doesn't really answer your question so I won't paste the whole analysis here.

The answer to your question as to why, when you run the code, nothing happens is that you never call `main`, you only define it.

```
def my_main():
    print("Do a bunch of stuff here!")

# never gets called
```

Nothing happens when you run this code. You have to do:

```
def my_main():
    print("Do a bunch of stuff here!")

main()
```

To make it run.

Now as I mentioned above: the code that you wrote won't do what you're trying to make it do. That issue, however, remains separate from it *not doing anything at all.* If you need some help implementing the changes I suggested in the link above, feel free to ask another question about a SPECIFIC problem you're having after having attempted the changes.

Comment: It greatly helps! I change the code and main, so far it pulls out a word. Do I need to create two files , one shuffle and one unshuffled in the code?

Comment: @get2thechopper I can't tell exactly what you're trying to do, so it's hard for me to advise how to proceed in your current code. If *I* were to write something like this, I'd do it like [this](https://gist.github.com/NotTheEconomist/d3707ae1246198592b43)